# Proving that is $A:X \implies Y$ is a linear operator from metric space X to Y is continuous iff it is bounded bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

The $\implies$ part interests me. The proof given goes like this:

Let $A$ be continuous in 0 (because the 0 vector is in every vector space)

$B_y(0,r)=\{y \in Y | \| y\|<r  \} \implies \exists B_x(0,s), A(B_s(0,s))\subset B_y(0,r), \sup_{\| x\|\subseteq S}\|Ax \| \leq r.$

Then it says for any

> $$x \in X: \|Ax\|= S^{-1}\|x\|\|A(\frac{Sx}{\|x\|})\|\leq S^{-1}r\|x\|
> > \implies \|Ax \| \leq M \|x \|$$

Comment: what is your question? and $S$ is some positive real, but what means then $\sup_{\| x\|\subseteq S}\|Ax \|$ or should it be $\sup_{\| x\|\leq S}\|Ax \|$ ?

Comment: My question is the clarification of the highlighted and what you wrote second should be correct i think

Comment: You are asking about normed spaces, not just metric spaces, right?  (Otherwise this doesn't make sense or is missing other assumptions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is the following:

first we state that $\sup_{\| x\|\leq S}\|Ax \|=\sup_{\| x\|= S}\|Ax \|\leq r \tag 1 $

then we see that for $x\in X$ the following holds, since $A$ is linear
$$
\|Ax\|= A\left (S^{-1}\|x\|\frac{Sx}{\|x\|}\right )=S^{-1}\|x\|\|A(\frac{Sx}{\|x\|})\|
$$
then we see that $\forall x\in X: \|\frac{Sx}{\|x\|}\|=S$ which means we can apply $(1)$ which gives us
$$
\|Ax\|=S^{-1}\|x\|\|A(\frac{Sx}{\|x\|})\|\leq S^{-1}\|x\|r=M\|x\|
$$ 
with $M:=S^{-1}r$. This means we have 
$$
\|Ax\|\leq M\|x\|
$$
and $A$ is bounded.
You can find a very nice proof also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503433/prove-that-if-a-linear-operator-is-continuous-then-it-is-bounded) by Anthony Carapetis.