# Prove identity map $i_X:(X, ||.||_1) \to (X, ||.||_2)$ is continuous, then $\exists L>0$ s.t. $\forall x \in X, ||x||_1 \le L||x||_2$

Tags: vector-spaces, continuity

The previous version is if there exists a positive real number L s.t. $\forall x \in X, ||x||_1 \le  L||x||_2$, then $i_X:(X, ||.||_1) \to (X, ||.||_2)$
is continuous.

My proof is following
\begin{align*}
\forall \alpha \in X, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta>0,  \delta < \epsilon/k \\\\
||x-\alpha||_1 <\delta &\Rightarrow ||i(x)-i(\alpha)||_2 \\\\
&=||x-\alpha||_2<L||x-\alpha||_1 < L\delta<\epsilon
\end{align*}

So the function is continuous. But the converse version is very confusing, I'm not sure if I should use contradiction or direct prove, can someone give a hint?

Comment: 1/3 What is $X$ (and $\|~\|_p$ on it)? Is it any real vector space and any two norms? this should be specified in your post.  2/3 The indices of your two norms in the inequality must be exchanged for your title, claim, and proof to be correct. 3/3 Delete this $\delta<\epsilon/k$ in the middle of your proof.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that if a linear operator is continuous, then it is bounded.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503433/prove-that-if-a-linear-operator-is-continuous-then-it-is-bounded)

Comment: Yes, that is very helpful.